# ActivityIndicator is not coming in proper position

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Please help me out how i will bring the activityIndicator in proper Position.
    In all Platform it is not coming in proper position,It is coming in top not in center of the device.

```
<ScrollView>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#3F51B5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Padding="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  >
              <Image Source="panel.jpg"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Padding="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
              <Entry />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Padding="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
              <Entry />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout  Padding="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
              <Label/>
            </StackLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name ="LoadingLogin" IsRunning="False" IsVisible="False" Color="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 1):

To have `ActivityIndicator` on the screen center you have to wrap it inside `ContentView` like this:

```
<ContentView HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="true">
     <ActivityIndicator x:Name ="LoadingLogin" IsRunning="False" IsVisible="False" Color="Black" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</ContentView>
```

And don't forget that all other views should have `IsVisible=false` when `ActivityIndicator` is shown.

Comment: have u test these code in all platforms it is working or not

Comment: Yes, I use it very often. It definitely works on every platform.

Comment: can u help me by using my code only how i will use your code because i m trying ur code it is not working

Comment: did your code block all the click event when activityIndicator is visible